# Get a value from a DataFrame in pandas by Row Name, NOT by Row Index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following Pandas DataFrame:

```
    1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
1  10   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
4   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
5   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
7   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

As you can see, the Row names are numbers that **is not the same index value.**

I don't have the Row name "6".

I would like to **set and get** the cell value **by Row Name** and Column Name, Not Row index.

I'm using:

pandas 1.0.1
Python 3.7.6

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "the Row names are numbers that is not the same index value". In pandas the index values __are__ `[1,2,4,5,7]`. I believe you're looking for [loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) which provides access via labels. `df.loc[1,1]` to get 10 (for example).

Comment: Thanks Henry! I thought that the pandas interpret the column as string , considering 1 as "1". This was my mistake.